# How to Create a Method to save user input

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

I have the following view here where the user is able to input three different items: **LockedOutBy**, **LockedOutFor**, and **LockedOutDate**. I am having trouble creating a method within my view-model to allow the user to input these three items and once they hit '**ok**', it will save the three items. Sorry if it is vague or if there is not enough info, please let me know if there is anything else needed.

Thank you.

**View**

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Locked Out By:"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LockedOutBy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Locked Out For:"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding LockedOutFor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Locked Out Date:"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding LockedOutDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<Button Command="{Binding Path=OKCommand}"
```

[image]

**View-Model**

This is what I have so far in my view-model.

```
private string _LockedOutFor;
        public string LockedOutFor
        {
            get { return _LockedOutFor; }
            set
            {
                _LockedOutFor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OwnerName");
            }
        }

        private string _LockedOutBy;
        public string LockedOutBy
        {
            get { return _LockedOutBy; }
            set
            {
                _LockedOutBy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Street");
            }
        }

        private int _LockedOutDate;
        public int LockedOutDate
        {
            get { return _LockedOutDate; }
            set
            {
                _LockedOutDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StreetOverflow");
            }
        }

public ICommand CancelCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(c => OnCancelLock()); }
        }

        public ICommand OKCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(c => OnOKLock()); }
        }

        protected void OnOKLock()
        {
            OnOK(LockedOutFor, LockedOutBy, LockedOutDate);
        }

        protected void OnCancelLock()
        {
            OnCancel();
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I tried creating an event runhandler with those parameters inside but that did not seem to work. I figured creating a method that would bind to the view would be the best solution, however, I am a bit lost as to how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANotifyPropertyChanged - base implementation for all of our view models

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace SO60269403
{
    public abstract class ANotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var areEqual = ReferenceEquals(backingStore, newValue);
            if (areEqual)
                return;
            backingStore = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

LockedOutViewModel - our view model

```
namespace SO60269403
{
    public class LockedOutViewModel : ANotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string lockedOutBy;
        private string lockedOutFor;
        private int lockedOutDate;

        public string LockedOutBy { get => lockedOutBy; set => SetProperty(ref lockedOutBy, value); }
        public string LockedOutFor { get => lockedOutFor; set => SetProperty(ref lockedOutFor, value); }
        public int LockedOutDate { get => lockedOutDate; set => SetProperty(ref lockedOutDate, value); }
    }
}
```

ACommand - base implementation for all of our commands

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SO60269403
{
    public abstract class ACommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

        public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
    }
}
```

SaveCommand - our save command

```
namespace SO60269403
{
    public class SaveCommand : ACommand
    {
        public LockedOutViewModel LockedOutViewModel { get; set; }

        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow - a view to data-bind our view model and hook up our save command

```
<Window
    x:Class="SO60269403.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO60269403">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:LockedOutViewModel
            x:Key="LockedOutViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid
        DataContext="{StaticResource LockedOutViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0">Locked Out By</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0">Locked Out For</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0">Locked Out Date</TextBlock>
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding LockedOutBy}" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding LockedOutFor}" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding LockedOutDate}" />
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Width"
                        Value="100" />
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Button>Cancel</Button>
            <Button>
                <Button.Command>
                    <local:SaveCommand
                        LockedOutViewModel="{StaticResource LockedOutViewModel}" />
                </Button.Command>
                OK
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

if we put a breakpoint in SaveCommand.Execute then run the app, fill in some values and click the OK button, the debugger should break on our breakpoint and we can observe that the view model's properties match what we entered. this demonstrates that the data is in place ready to be saved.